# How to get display value of field from controller in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I have a component on my view:

```
{
    xtype : 'socekiliscombo',
    name : 'socekilisOid',
    labelSeparator : '',
    anchor : '25%',
    allowBlank : false,
    itemId : 'socekilis',
    params : {},
    listeners : {
    specialkey : Ext.emptyFn
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to get this component's display value from a controller. First I tried to get the component itself, but unable to do it. I tried this:

```
var socekilistarihi = this.getTalihliKayitPanel().getComponent('#socekilis');
```

I get a value of "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard controller refferences.

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    refs: [{
        ref: 'socekilis',
        selector: '#socekilis'
    }],
    getComponentValue: function(){
        var component = this.getSocekilis();
        var value = null;
        if(component){
            value = component.getValue();
        }
        return value;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var socekilisCombo = this.getTalihliKayitPanel().down('socekiliscombo[name="socekilisOid"]'),
    socekilisComboValue;
if (socekilisCombo)
{
    socekilisComboValue = socekilisCombo.getValue(); 
}
```

And check this component really on talihliKayitPanel.

Comment: I need display value of this component. This gives me the id of the element.

Comment: this one worked: var socekilistarihiValue = socekilisCombo.getRawValue();

Comment: yes, because i did not know what you want and i did not know what a component you use, getValue - return id of value, getRawValue - return that you see. Usually requires exactly id of value if you use combobox components.